# Correct Certification but provisioning profile invalid

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

Is there a bug in Xcode 6.1 because this happen the 2nd time now. My provisioning profile suddenly became invalid but it has the correct certification.

This is the way I update the provisioning profile

1. Create new certRequest
2. Create new distribution/development cert

EDIT: These first 2 steps are only executed once.

3. Update old provisioning profile to the newly created cert

EDIT: this step is important because my old cert has expired.

4. Open Xcode 6.1
5. Xcode > Preferences > Accounts >View Details > Refresh
6. open iPhone configuration utility to check if it updates

and then when I compile my app it compiles just fine but after 24hrs and checked it again in member center it's now invalid but has the correct cert

**Additional Info:** We have 2 distribution Cert **Oct 19,2015** and **Oct 20,2015** and I'm using **oct 20,2015** because it has my certRequest in there

[image]

Comment: No, not a bug. You shouldn't update Provisioning Profile like this (first 3 steps are not required). You have 2 choices: 1. Click Refresh in Xcode and it will do the job for you; 2. Delete the old PP in Member Portal, then create a new one.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I only did the first 3 steps once. I'll just edit my question

Comment: It happened to me a few days ago.  I recreated provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still investigating but so far the problem is when I revoke my push cert to create a new one my provisioning profile will became invalid.